# Golang: Does logging into file using log.Println takes care of concurrent access

Tags: logging, file-io, go, buffer

I have hundreds of subroutines writing into log file using log.Println() 
I am using log.Println to write into error.log file.

```
func main() {
  e, err := os.OpenFile("error.log", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error opening file: %v", err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
  defer e.Close()
  errLog := log.New(e, ">>>", log.Ldate|log.Ltime)

  for i:=0; i<500; i++ {
      go worker(errLog)
  }
}

func worker(errLog log.Logger) {
  // Do some work 
  errLog.Println("Hello world!!!")
}
```

Is my approach correct ? Or should I use channel to make sure only one process is logging into file at one time or is it taken care of inherently by log package?

Also does log package takes care of buffering or it directly writes into file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [log.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/log/log.go):

```
func (l *Logger) Output(calldepth int, s string) error {
   now := time.Now() // get this early.
   var file string
   var line int
   l.mu.Lock()
   defer l.mu.Unlock()
   // ... Rest omitted
```

Since pretty much all package `log` output functions go through `Output`, and there's a mutex in `Output` it's safe to say they're concurrency-safe.

Answer (score 19):

I really can recommend reading the documentation:

> A Logger represents an active logging object that generates lines of output to an io.Writer. Each logging operation makes a single call to the Writer's Write method. A Logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines; it guarantees to serialize access to the Writer.

See http://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger

Comment: Ohh I read the description at the top, I did not read about Logger, My bad

Comment: I searched for "concurrent" since most packages seem to comment regarding safe use of "concurrent goroutines". I missed this since I wasn't expecting "simultaneously" to be the search term.